# awk: parse columns like: [1,2,3] in csv file

Tags: regex, csv, awk

I have a csv file that looks like so:

```
a, b, c
1, 2, [1, 2, 3]
4, 5, [7, 7, 7, 7, 8]
5, 3, []
6, 5, [45, 45, 2, 1, 2, 8, 8]
```

I would like to extract the third column via `awk`, which to me means telling `awk` that the field separator is any comma not inside a pair of brackets. So I would like to extract:

```
c
1,2,3
7, 7, 7, 7, 8

4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 8, 8
```

I tried using a regular expression to set the `FS Field Separator` like so on the Ubuntu command line:

```
awk '{FS = ["^\[],[^\]]"} {print $3}' file.csv
```

But this printed out:

```
c
[
[
[]
[4
```

which is not even close to what I like. Is this a problem with how I am defining my field separator or have I done something else wrong as well? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern as field separator:

```
awk -F '^[^,]*,[^,]*, [[]?|]' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gnu-awk` with `FPAT`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\\[[^]]*\\]|[^,]*,? *" } {gsub(/[][]/, "", $3); print $3}' file.csv
c
1, 2, 3
7, 7, 7, 7, 8

45, 45, 2, 1, 2, 8, 8
```

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/26GVVt)

---

**EDIT:** Non-gnu (BSD) awk  solution:

```
awk -F ', *' '{$1=$2=""; gsub(/^ *|[][]/, "", $0);} 1' file.csv
c
1 2 3
7 7 7 7 8

45 45 2 1 2 8 8
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It is almost there, but when I run it, this only returns the first number int he list: 1 7 blank 45 rather than the full list for each line.

Comment: Make sure you're using gnu-awk. I am using `GNU Awk 4.1.1`

Comment: If GNU Awk 4.x is not available, here is a solution using sed.       sed 's/[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,],\(.*\)/\1/'

Answer (score 0):

You could also just match the third field using a plain csv regex.
This is a slightly Perl'ish expression (uses branch reset).
Don't know if *grep* or *sed* in Perl mode would work.

*edit: disqualify empty string*

```
 # (?m)^(?:(?:^|,)[^\S\r\n]*(?|\[([^\[\]\r\n]*)\]|([^,\r\n]*?))(?:[^\S\r\n]*(?=$|,))){3}(?!^)

 (?m)
 ^ 
 (?:                      # Cluster
      (?: ^ | , )              # Delimiter
      [^\S\r\n]*               # Trim leading optional whitespaces
      (?|
           \[                       # Quoted [ ]
           ( [^\[\]\r\n]* )         # (1)
           \]
        |                         # or
           ( [^,\r\n]*? )           # (1), Non-quoted
      )
      (?:
           [^\S\r\n]*               # Trim trailing optional whitespaces 
           (?= $ | , )              # Ahead, delimiter
      )
 ){3}                     # The third field
 (?! ^ )                  # Disqualify empty string
```